# How to pass a macro as an argument in a C function?

Tags: c, macros, function-pointers

I want to pass a macro as an argument in a C function, and I don't know if it possible.
I would like to see this operation, for instance:

I have these macros:

```
#define PRODUCT(A, B) ((A) * (B)) 
#define SUM(A, B) ((A) + (B))
```

And then I have this function with the following signature:

```
int just_a_function(int x, MACRO_AS_PARAMATER_HERE);
```

and then i want to call this function like:

```
just_a_function(10, SUM);
```

is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: please don't do this.

Comment: Macros are *expanded prior* to the code being parsed/compiled as C.

Comment: You can pass it to a macro function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that.

Use normal functions instead:

```
int sum(int x, int y)
{
    return x+y;
}

//...

just_another_function(10, sum);
```

Note: `just_another_function` must accept `int (*)(int, int)` as the second argument.

```
typedef int (*TwoArgsFunction)(int, int);
int just_another_function(int x, TwoArgsFunction fun);
```

Comment: Thank you for the example and answer.

Answer (score 15):

You can't pass as function argument.

But if function is a macro this is possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRODUCT(A, B) ((A) * (B)) 
#define SUM(A, B) ((A) + (B))
#define JUST_A_FUNCTION(A, B, MACRO) MACRO(A, B)

int main() {
        int value;

        value = JUST_A_FUNCTION(10, 10, SUM);
        printf("%d\n", value);

        value = JUST_A_FUNCTION(10, 10, PRODUCT);
        printf("%d\n", value);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi what you are passing is macro means its a substitution your passing . Think about it ..
Ex : #define HIGH 1
In a function you can use int variable. So you can pass 1 to the function . In a function its stored as integer variable

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor directive works first . Once in a main macro are replaced means in the sense in a function you have to take care of the substitution. If I would have used Macro High 1 ,, in function I will take as int as a argument to get for local function stack. For better understanding check the topics 1.preprocessor directive 2. How the hex file created once you will compile

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#define HIGH 1
#define LOW 0

void pin(int, int);

void pin(int a, int b) { 
  printf("A: %d B: %d\n", a, b);
}

int main() {
  pin(1, HIGH);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation step involve:

1. pre processor directive
2. compiler
3. linker
4. executable file